# Standardising / whitening / rescaling data by group with R

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

I have some grouped data that has features with very different ranges. I want to standardise each feature by group. Additionally, I would like to perform this on an arbitrarily large selection of features (supplied by name e.g. `standardise.vars` below). What is the best way to do this in R?

My approach so far is given in the following stupid example:

```
DT <- data.table(mtcars)
group.vars <- c('cyl', 'am')
setkeyv(DT, group.vars)
standardise.vars <- c('disp','hp')
mns <- DT[, lapply(.SD, mean), .SDcols = standardise.cols, by = group.vars]
sds <- DT[, lapply(.SD, sd), .SDcols = standardise.cols, by = group.vars]
merged <- merge(mns, sds, suffixes = c('.mean', '.sd'))
DT[merged, ]
```

This leaves me with my standardisation columns having their means and standard deviations printed next to them. I now need to perform the operation `(x - x.mean) / x.std` for all columns `x`.

```
     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb disp.mean   hp.mean   disp.sd    hp.sd
 1: 24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2  135.8667  84.66667 13.969371 19.65536
 2: 22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2  135.8667  84.66667 13.969371 19.65536
 3: 21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1  135.8667  84.66667 13.969371 19.65536
...
```

However, I feel this is a bad approach and that I could have achieved the standardisation in one step. Any help, pointers towards my misuse of `data.table`, or potential to use `dplyr` much appreciated.

This approach using `scale` comes close but it's not in a nice format (removing the `list(...)` from around `scale` causes error):

```
DT[, list(disp.scaled = list(scale(disp)), 
     hp.scaled = list(scale(hp))), by = .(cyl,am)]

   cyl am                                                        disp.scaled
1:   4  0                                    0.7755062, 0.3531536,-1.1286597
2:   4  1  0.7026252,-0.7282640,-0.8747715,-1.0994162,-0.7136133, 1.3033057,
3:   6  0                         1.1946100, 0.4570585,-0.8258343,-0.8258343
4:   6  1                                    0.5773503, 0.5773503,-1.1547005
5:   8  0  0.0331832, 0.0331832,-1.1391352,-1.1391352,-1.1391352, 1.5925615,
6:   8  1                                               0.7071068,-0.7071068
                                                            hp.scaled
1:                                   -1.1532051, 0.5257259, 0.6274793
2:  0.4910526,-0.7007155,-1.3186693,-0.7448550,-0.7007155, 0.4027735,
3:                        -0.5719714,-1.1167062, 0.8443388, 0.8443388
4:                                   -0.5773503,-0.5773503, 1.1547005
5: -0.5745432, 1.5237884,-0.4246623,-0.4246623,-0.4246623, 0.3247418,
6:                                              -0.7071068, 0.7071068
```

And this approach using `dplyr` is really close but is doing something weird with the `group_by_` (it works with a `group_by`):

```
ans <- DT %>% group_by(cyl, am) %>% 
    mutate_each_(funs(scale), standardise.vars)
ans2 <- DT %>% group_by_(group.vars) %>% 
    mutate_each_(funs(scale), standardise.vars)
truth <- filter(DT,am==0,cyl==4) %>% 
    transmute((disp - mean(disp))/sd(disp))
cbind(DT[,.(cyl,am,disp)], ans[,disp], ans2[,disp], truth)[1:3]

   cyl am  disp         V2       V3 (disp - mean(disp))/sd(disp)
1:   4  0 146.7  0.7755062 1.546750                    0.7755062
2:   4  0 140.8  0.3531536 1.327187                    0.3531536
3:   4  0 120.1 -1.1286597 0.556857                   -1.1286597
```

Comment: Yes, but can I apply this to a list columns by group?

Comment: Apologies if I'm being a little dense here, but I see no option to perform the operation by group in `lapply` or `scale`. Would you mind expanding your solution in an answer below?

Comment: I've added a clarification above if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say we want to standardise the variables in `standardise.vars` by the variables in group defined by `group.vars`:

```
DT <- data.table(mtcars)
group.vars <- c('cyl', 'am')
standardise.vars <- c('disp','hp')
```

I think this solution with `dplyr` solves it:

```
DT <- DT %>% group_by_(.dots=group.vars) %>% 
    mutate_each_(funs(scale), standardise.vars)
```

And for completeness, you can do it via `data.table` like this:

```
myscale <- function(x){
    (x - mean(x)) / sd(x)
}
DT[, (standardise.vars) := lapply(.SD, myscale), 
   .SDcols = standardise.vars, by = group.vars]
```